# What package contains '%<>%' operator in R

Tags: r

https://scholar.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/bstewart/files/srg_crossval.pdf

Following along with these slides the code uses a '%<>%' operator.

Does anyone know what this is or what package it is used in?

The code reads

```
# Function to divide data into folds randomly
fold <- function(data, k) {
data <- data[sample(nrow(data)),] # Shuffle data
data %<>% mutate(fold = cut(seq(1:nrow(data)), breaks = k, labels=FALSE))
return(data)
}
# Function to cross-validate data on given model (curried)
cv.predict.logit <- function(data, dv, model.fx, k) {
data %<>% fold(k) # Fold data
aucs <- c()
for(i in 1:k) {
# Divide data into train and test sets
train <- data %>% filter(fold != i)
test <- data %>% filter(fold == i)
# Estimate model on training data
mx <- model.fx(data=train)
# Predict on test data and calculate AUC
preds <- predict(mx, newdata=test, type="response")
AUC <- somers2(preds, test[[dv]])[1]
aucs[i] <- AUC
}
return(mean(aucs, na.rm=TRUE)) # Yield mean AUC
}
# Function to rerun CV results n times and average AUCs
crossval <- function(data, dv, model.fx, k, n) {
aucs <- replicate(n, cv.predict.logit(data, dv, model.fx, k))
return(aucs)
}
```

Comment: For future reference, you can use `??` to answer questions like this. e.g. `??\`%<>%\`` searches CRAN for `%<>%` and shows `magrittr::%<>%` as a result

Answer (score 2):

It's an [assignment pipe](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/compound.html) from the `magrittr` package:

> Pipe an object forward into a function or call expression and update the lhs object with the resulting value.